# C# WebService response with bytes

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a simple web service which returns a bunch of bytes.

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public byte[] GetBytes(string key)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("You said " + key);
}
```

When I send request it replies with:

```
<base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">WW91IHNhaWQgdGVzdA==</base64Binary>
```

I want to have in response is only `WW91IHNhaWQgdGVzdA==` without `base64Binary` tag - what did I miss?

Thank you!

Comment: what happens when you change your `WrappedRequest` to `Bare`

Comment: also what is key here and how are you sending the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've done it with:

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public Stream EchoWithPost(string key)
{
    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("You said " + key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using web service. So ***default content type of web service (asmx) is always `application/soap+xml`***.So the content represented will be in xml format.That is why although you are returning `byte[]` array,the response it will produce will have `base64` encoded in soap body.

By design wise you have above said limitation so if your purpose is only to return bytes then consider using

`Response.BinaryWrite` or http handler.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this Response.BinaryWrite in my POST method. I has to use POST method with binary answer I can't access to edit client.